# Python for statement. Has to break on the last data of the loop

Tags: python

I have to process 300 rows and write the data on excel file using openpyxl. I'm using for loop to process the rows. But if 'End' word comes, then the loop breaks and goes to the 501st row.

My issue is that the on 300th row the 'End' word is there. So the last row and 'End' word comes together. Logically, the program should break and go to 501 row. But my program ignores the 'End' word, process the 300th row and jumps to 301st row.

```
for count_300 in range (155, 300):
            cell_value_Y = ws.cell(row = row_break, column = Col_Y).value
            if( cell_value_Y == 'End') and (re.search(r'\Slide\b', cell_value_Z)): 
                row_break += 1
                loop_break = 'TRUE'
                print ('Break inside the loop =', cell_value_Y)
                break
```

Comment: Are you sure the value is `'End'` and not `' End'` or `End '` or `End\n'` (etc)?

Comment: Yes, the word is MovieEnd.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense to me. `'MovieEnd' != 'End'`. What is the value of `cell_value_Y` where you want it to break? (Print it or look at it in the debugger.)

Comment: if the word is "MovieEnd" then the argument is  if( 'End' in cell_value_Y )

Comment: Basic sanity check: do you know that `range (155, 300)` does not include 300?

Answer (score 1):

You could user `endswith` function

```
>>> cell_value_Y='MovieEnd'
>>> cell_value_Y.endswith('End')
True
```

Please refer [string functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) for other useful functions builtin for string

Comment: also increment range to range (155, 301) as per @Eric Leviell comment. else it will only ever reach cell 299